# Why does my crosshatch shader change between files?

Tags: shaders

Why does my crosshatch shader change between files?

The difference is considerable. I pasted my material into the new one, but it acted as if just the noise is showing. Nothing else works as intended. I'm using EEVEE, one light, UVs are done.

Somehow this shader changes for me between files.

I didn't change the other parts of the shader, except maybe the parts shown in the picture that control how big is the amount of crosshatching.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the entire node setup so that I can try to recreate the problem? If possible can you provide the blend file?(Will be much quicker for me than setting up the entire node tree)

Comment: If you import ("append") the object with the shader from one file to another, there's also an inconsistency? Otherwise it doesn't change between files, it just changes between objects.

Answer (score 0):

Because the material uses a *Shader to RGB* node, everything in the scene affects the look of the shader. Especially lighting.

In the World shader, I turned the color of the *Background* node back to gray color, which emits less light in the environment.

[image: here the white color made it all look wrong]

Also, my lighting was a sun with 100 strength instead of 1. I fixed that and then everything was working again.

Comment: That's the point of the `Shader to RGB` node, to turn the effects of the environments and light to your shader into malleable color.